# Use Ruby array to iterate and display in view using JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make a ajax call which will return and array of objects and display it on view.. I can display a single object of my class location but not able to iterate through array. I get the following error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class):
```

My js file is

```
 $("#locations").append("<%= escape_javascript(render(@locations)) %>");
```

My partial file is _location.erb is

```
<div id="locations" class="locations">
  <% unless @locations.nil %>
    <% @locations.each do |location| %>
      <%= @locations.name %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

My controller looks like

```
 def search
   result = getResultFromSomeWhere
   @locations = Array.new(result.size)
   result.each do |resultobj|
     @locations.push(Location.new(resultobj))
   end
   respond_to do |format|
     format.js
   end
 end
```

I think its something to do with serialization as i am passing array of ActiveRecord objects?

Comment: i figured the problem... I was getting the error because i already create @locations = Array.new(result.size) and this creates a set of nil objects, which while iterating was throwing error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say the size of result is 5, so then

`@locations = Array.new(result.size)` will return `[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]`

and then you're pushing locations to that array

```
[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, location1, location2, ...]
```

Then you can see your mistake.